# Expo Standalone iOS App Returns 'Undetermined' Permissions But Works Everywhere Else

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, expo

I have an Expo app that isn't getting permissions on iOS. I follow the [expo guide](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/#if-you-choose-to-build-for-ios), had expo generate my certificates, used basically exactly the code from the [push notification docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/guides/push-notifications/), allowed push notifications in the app, but iOS always returns 'undetermined' permissions. Running my app in the Expo app on my phone works, Android works, just not the actual iOS app. From what I can find, there doesn't need to be anything in app.json about notifications, right?

Here's the registration function, just for reference:

```
export async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
    Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
  );
  let finalStatus = existingStatus;

  if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    finalStatus = status;
  }

  // Status is always 'undetermined' on iOS standalone app.
  if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
    return;
  }

  // Get the token that uniquely identifies this device
  let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();

  // POST the token to your backend server from where you can retrieve it to send push notifications.
  return fetch(settings.api_url + 'push-token', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      push_token: token,
      api_key: ui.user.api_key
    }),
  });
}
```

Other info:

- Expo SDK 32
- iPhone XR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but since it has not been answered, I'll gather the common steps for fixing this.

If you're receiving status "undetermined" when testing the app through TestFlight or an actual install from the App Store, then you need to configure your **push notification certificate for production**. I'm sure you also received an email with saying something about **ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement**.

You need to do two or three things...

First, [the things mentioned here](https://github.com/expo/turtle/issues/62#issuecomment-469528206):

> In order to fix this, you need to enable "Push notifications" for your
>   app on the app store.
>
> 1. Login to https://developer.apple.com/
> 2. Go to the "Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles" section
> 3. Select "App IDs" in the Identifiers section on the left column
> 4. Choose your app ID, edit it and check "Push Notifications". Save changes
> 5. Generate a certificate for the production push service: go to the "Certificates" section, and follow the assistant to add a "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)" certificate for your app. Acute readers will notice that expo does not need this certificate since it uses a key to talk to Apple directly
>
> TL;DR: Expo needs to enable the "Push Notification" service when creating the app in the Apple Developer Portal

Second, I'm sure you already has published you app, so what you need to do is change the `expo.ios.buildNumber` in your **app.json** file and then rebuild the app with the clear provisioning profile param like this:

```sh
expo build:ios --clear-provisioning-profile
```

In that way Expo will generate the build with the Push Notifications that are now activated in your App ID Identifier.

Finally, upload it again from the Application Loader. You should be fine.

Hope this helps.

**IMPORTANT.** If clearing just the provisioning file doesn't work, try *clearing all* with the command `expo build:ios -c`